# Can bucketing strategy be controlled per template?

Tags: buckets

Bucketing is a nice feature for organizing a large amount of items in the Sitecore content tree, however the default bucketing strategy based on item creation date is mostly useful for content where the creation date is actually relevant (e.g. news articles).

Can multiple bucketing strategies co-exist in the same Sitecore solution? Is it possible to create a different bucketing strategy based on the bucket item template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to change the format of the default bucketing folder structure uising the following setting:

```
<setting name="BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath" value="yyyy\/MM\/dd\/HH\/mm"/>
```

Note that this is still based on the item creation date though.

It is also possible to utilise the Sitecore Rules Engine to determine the folder structure, updating the rules on `/sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Item Buckets Settings` in the content tree.

Out of the box the following rules are available:

[image: Sitecore Buckets Rules Editor]

The first rule is pretty much the same as the default naming using config settings, but it does allow you to set a different format per bucket folder. The other 2 rules use the item ID or name and then create nested folders based on that.

If none of rules meet your requirements then it is possible to create a custom rule and utlise that instead. For example, to create the folder based on the user creating the item and the year you could use:

```
public class UserBasedPath<T> : RuleAction where T : BucketingRuleContext
{
  public override void Apply(T ruleContext)
  {
    if (Sitecore.Context.Data != null && Sitecore.Context.Data.User != null)
    {
      ruleContext.ResolvedPath = 
        Sitecore.Context.Data.User.LocalName + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year;
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to register the rule under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements/Bucketing` and set the `Text` and `Type` fields to match your rules and the it will be available for use in the Rule Set Editor.

Comment: Is this approach preferred over dynamic bucket folder?

Comment: @KasperGadensgaard It depends on your requirement. If *all* your bucket item folders need to be in exactly the same structure then `BucketConfiguration.DynamicBucketFolderPath` setting is a good option. However, if different bucket folders have different folder structure requirements (e.g. news items vs blog posts) the using the Rules Engine to set these is preferable.

Comment: I need different bucketing strategies per template, so it sounds like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `Sitecore.Buckets.Util.IDynamicBucketFolderPath` to make your own logic. There is one method to implement, where you have `templateId` - among others - as a parameter:

```cs
string GetFolderPath(Database database, string name, ID templateId, ID newItemId, ID parentItemId, DateTime creationDateOfNewItem);
```

Then point the setting `BucketConfiguration.DynamicBucketFolderPath` to your class.

Comment: So setting the **BucketConfiguration.DynamicBucketFolderPath** will ignore the setting of **BucketConfiguration.BucketFolderPath**?

Comment: @KasperGadensgaard If you don't plan to use it in your logic, yes. It is used by the default `BucketFolderPathResolver` and by the `DateBasedFolderPath` implementations. Another predefined bucket path resolver is `GuidFolderPath`.